# Bokeh widget to select a group from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

I have a data set sort of like this:

```
fruits = ["orange", "plum", "lime"]
data = [(random.choice(fruits), 
         random.randint(0,100), 
         random.randint(0,100)) for i in range(16)]
dframe = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["fruit", "x", "y"])
```

where `fruit` has only a few values. I want a select widget so you can pick which kind of fruit you want to see in the plot.

Here's the update function I currently have:

```
source = bk.ColumnDataSource(dframe)
by_fruit = dframe.groupby('fruit')

def update(fruit):
    grouped = by_fruit.get_group(fruit)
    source.data['x'] = grouped['x']
    source.data['y'] = grouped['y']
    source.data['fruit'] = grouped['fruit']
    source.push_notebook()

interact(update, fruit=fruits)
```

but going through and re-assigning the values of each column seems excessively verbose as I get more columns. It's error-prone, as if I leave out a column, they become different lengths and get misaligned.

Pandas excels at slicing and dicing things, and I feel like I'm missing something. What's a more concise way to change the `Series` in each column of the `ColumnDataSource` at the same time?

[[This example in an IPython Notebook](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/keturn/8c23e5648de899a6aee9)]

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate over the columns of `grouped`:

```
def update(fruit):
    grouped = by_fruit.get_group(fruit)
    for col in grouped:
        source.data[col] = grouped[col]
    source.push_notebook()
```

Comment: Yes, this is a clear improvement, as it avoids the problem of forgetting to update it when you add or remove columns. Pandas usually has some clever way to operate on all columns without a for loop, though. But maybe that's something lost in the conversion to bokeh's ColumnDataSource.

Comment: There's probably lots of small improvements to spelling that can be made, please submit any suggestions for improvements on the Bokeh GH issue tracker!

Comment: I discovered iterating over the pandas groupby omits its index column. ColumnDataSource.from_df handles it separately: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/0.7.0/bokeh/models/sources.py#L54 so any update function like this must handle it as well.